# Unique Clicks per Subscriber and Unique Clicks per subscriber per link/url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, sfmc-datorama

I am trying to achieve following results using SFMC data views and SQL but unable to produce a query that can meet all these requirements in one piece of code.

[image]

Also, my requirement is to create a net CTR for each link clicked based on the formula in screenshot above. That is how link's net CTR is calculated in SFMC's email studio when we see link tracking and link performance, but not sure how to bring total emails sent per job in each row against links as I will be implementing on whole send history in SFMC.

**EDIT:**

First Query Posted by CharlieFay works for most parts, except I am not getting consistent number for total emails sent and total bounces. I want these numbers to remain constant for that send so I can calculate net CTR for each link. SQL code I am running in Query Builder is below.

```
    SELECT
    c.SubscriberKey,
    c.AccountID,
    c.jobId,
    j.EmailName,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.SubscriberKey)   AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey)                     AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    LEFT(c.LinkName,50)                                 AS LinkName,
    LEFT(c.LinkContent,50)                              AS LinkContent,
    COUNT(*)                                            AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey)                     AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link,
    SUM(s.SendCount) as Total_Emails_Sent,
    SUM(b.BounceCount) as Total_Emails_Bounced
   
FROM 
    [_Click] AS c
    
LEFT JOIN [_Job] AS j
ON c.jobID=j.jobID

CROSS APPLY (
    Select COUNT(SubscriberKey) AS SendCount
    from [_Sent]
    where jobID = c.jobID 
    ) s
CROSS APPLY (
    Select COUNT(SubscriberKey) AS BounceCount
    from [_Bounce]
    where jobID = c.jobID
    ) b
WHERE 
    c.JobID = '367510' 
GROUP BY 
    c.SubscriberKey,
    c.AccountID,
    c.jobId, 
    j.EmailName,
    c.LinkName, 
    c.LinkContent
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will output the totals and unique counts similar to your desired output. Hopefully this can assist getting you on the right direction.

```
SELECT
    c.SubscriberKey,
    c.jobId,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.SubscriberKey)   AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey)                     AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    LEFT(c.LinkName,50)                                 AS LinkName,
    LEFT(c.LinkContent,50)                              AS LinkContent,
    COUNT(*)                                            AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey)                     AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link
FROM 
    [_Click] AS c
WHERE 
    c.JobID = '_____' 
GROUP BY 
    c.SubscriberKey, 
    c.jobId, 
    c.LinkName, 
    c.LinkContent
```

Note that Query Studio sometimes has issues with COUNT(DISTINCT). Run in AutomationStudio to verify.

And a modified approach...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    jobId,
    SubscriberKey,
    MAX(rn_SubKey) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId)                              AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    MAX(dr_SubKey) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId)                              AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    LEFT(LinkName,50)                                                                   AS LinkName,
    LEFT(LinkContent,50)                                                                AS LinkContent,
    MAX(rn_SkLinkClick)  OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId,LinkName,LinkContent)   AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link,
    MAX(dr_rn_SkLinkClick) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId,LinkName,LinkContent) AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SubscriberKey,
            LinkName, 
            LinkContent,
            URL,
            IsUnique,
            jobId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId ORDER BY SubscriberKey)                         AS rn_SubKey,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId ORDER BY SubscriberKey)                         AS dr_SubKey,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId,LinkName,LinkContent ORDER BY SubscriberKey)    AS rn_SkLinkClick,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey,JobId,LinkName,LinkContent ORDER BY SubscriberKey)    AS dr_rn_SkLinkClick
        FROM 
            [_Click] AS c
        WHERE 1=1
            AND JobID = '_______' 
    ) AS x
```

And yet another approach with the same output, but written differently:

```
SELECT 
    c.SubscriberKey,
    c.jobId,
    tc.Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    uc.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    LEFT(c.LinkName,50)    AS LinkName,
    LEFT(c.LinkContent,50) AS LinkContent,
    tlc.Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link,
    utlc.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            jobId,
            SubscriberKey,
            LinkName, 
            LinkContent,
            URL,
            IsUnique
        FROM 
            [_Click]
        WHERE 1=1
            AND JobID = '_____' 
    ) AS c
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId,
            COUNT(*) AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job
        FROM 
            [_Click] AS t2
        WHERE 
            c.SubscriberKey = t2.SubscriberKey 
            AND c.JobId = t2.JobId
        GROUP BY
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId
    ) AS tc
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId,
            COUNT(DISTINCT SubscriberKey) AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job
        FROM 
            [_Click] AS t2
        WHERE 
            c.SubscriberKey = t2.SubscriberKey 
            AND c.JobId = t2.JobId
        GROUP BY
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId
    ) AS uc
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId,
            LinkName, 
            LinkContent,
            COUNT(SubscriberKey) AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link
        FROM 
            [_Click] AS t2
        WHERE 
            c.SubscriberKey = t2.SubscriberKey 
            AND c.JobId = t2.JobId 
            AND (c.LinkName = t2.LinkName OR (c.LinkName IS NULL AND t2.LinkName IS NULL))
            AND c.LinkContent = t2.LinkContent
        GROUP BY
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId,
            LinkName, 
            LinkContent
    ) AS tlc
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId,
            LinkName, 
            LinkContent,
            COUNT(DISTINCT SubscriberKey) AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link
        FROM 
            [_Click] AS t2
        WHERE 
            c.SubscriberKey = t2.SubscriberKey 
            AND c.JobId = t2.JobId 
            AND (c.LinkName = t2.LinkName OR (c.LinkName IS NULL AND t2.LinkName IS NULL))
            AND c.LinkContent = t2.LinkContent
        GROUP BY
            SubscriberKey, 
            jobId,
            LinkName, 
            LinkContent
    ) AS utlc
GROUP BY
    c.SubscriberKey,
    c.jobId,
    tc.Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    uc.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job,
    c.LinkName,
    c.LinkContent,
    tlc.Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link,
    utlc.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_Per_Job_Per_Link
```

Comment: Thanks @charliefay. Really appreciate your response. Let me try this and will update my comments accordingly. I have updated my questions to add some additional requirements as well, as there is no way except SQL in SFMC to calculate net CTR for links on whole email history. Email studio only provided link performance by job id (means one job at a time)

Comment: First Query worked in Query Builder and results seems good except net URL CTR which I still need to calculate but when I run same query in automation studio nothing gets populated in target DE even thought query is same with no syntax error. In Query builder I can't save the results into DE and keep getting error "Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'." for all thee queries when i select DE name from the left pane and hit validate